# How to preserve new audio when importing Premiere projects into After Effects?

Tags: premiere, after-effects

I am working on a project in Adobe Premiere consisting of many small clips. For some of the clips I replaced the audio by unlinking the original videoclip from the original audioclip, cutting the audioclip from the timeline, replacing it with the new audiofile and relinking the original videoclip with the new audioclip.

When I import this Premiere project into After Effects however, all clips have their original audio again and while the new audiofiles appear in the new project view, they are nowhere to be found on the timeline.

How can I make sure the videoclips will be correctly imported with the new associated audioclip instead of their original audio?